# java libraries specifically for use with windows

Tags: java, windows, interop

**Background:** A long time I remember reading about a Java library that was created specifically to handle routine operations on Windows operating systems. It had, for example, native routines for handling things like "shortcut" creation, and all those cute little quirks of windows filepaths.

It was touted as being the "missing library" for doing all those windows tasks that were harder than they should be using the standard Java APIs.

**Question:** That's about all I remember about it, does anyone have a link to help refresh my vague recall?

Comment: I've just spent this last year slowly adding to such a library.  I'd love to know if there's a "proper" one :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of [WinPack](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/winpack/)?  It's a JNI-based wrapper that provides access to a lot of underlying Windows functionality.

Comment: +1 That's being used by IntelliJ Idea since the beginning, I wonder if it is shiped with the new Open Source version of Idea?

Comment: Looks nice, but the one I am thinking of was much lower-level. It just had tools for things like .CreateShortcut() .GetDriveLetter() ... that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you refer to: [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/twall/jna/)?

Comment: That looks close, but it was just some random open-source library out there. Windows API calls were simply wrapped with methods like CreateWindowsShortcut(), GetDriveLetter()

Answer (score 1):

At a somewhat lower level, there's the [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/) library which allows you to make OLE/COM calls from Java code.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [JDIC (JDesktop Integration Components)](https://jdic.dev.java.net/)

JDIC provides Java applications with access to functionalities and facilities provided by the native desktop. It consists of a collection of Java packages and tools. JDIC supports a variety of features such as embedding the native browser, launching the desktop applications, creating tray icons on the desktop, registering file type associations, creating JNLP installer packages, etc.

There does not seem to be a lot of activity in the project lately, however.